# Package Algorithmic in French

Tags: algorithms

I use

```
\usepackage[section]{algorithm}  
\usepackage{algorithmic}
```

to create an algorithm, I'd like to change "`algorithm`, `begin`, `end while` ..." to French. Is that possible?

This is my example with the package `\usepackage{algorithmic}`:

```
\newcommand{\algorithmicfor}{\textbf{Pour}}
\begin{algorithm}[H] 
\Begin{ \For{$x\in X$}{ $NbSuccInS(x) 
\longleftarrow 0$\; $NbPredInMin(x) 
\longleftarrow 0$\; $NbPredNotInMin(x) 
\longleftarrow |ImPred(x)|$\; 
} } 
\caption{My Algorithm} \label{alg:test} 
 \end{algorithm}
```

I have these errors: `undefined control sequence \Begin \for, \newcommand` ....

Comment: please make this a complete document showing all packages used

Comment: Those errors are unrelated to the translation to French problem, you wuld get them even without the redefinition from `For` to `Pour` (which would need to be `\renewcommand` not `\newcommand` . It is _much_ easier to answer questions if they contain a single code section starting `\documentclass` and ending `\end{document}` If your question had a working document using english keywords someone could show you how to redefine the commands to make it use French keywords. `algorithmic` appears to define `\FOR` not `\For` and doesn't define `\Begin` as far as I can see.

Comment: thank you for answer but i can't find in the list Algorithm
--> Algorithme have you an idea please ?

Comment: That's from algorithm.sty not algorithmic `\newcommand{\ALG@name}{Algorithm}
\newcommand{\listalgorithmname}{List of \ALG@name s}
` to rename `\ALG@name` you need \makeatletter \makeatother but _please_ post a _complete_example that works in English then it is easy to post an answer using French.then

Comment: i add this \renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Algorithm} \renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{List of \ALG@name s} \makeatletter \makeatother in \begin{document} ?

Comment: This is why you should provide a complete example in the question handling code fragments in comments is difficult and error prone  `\makeatletter\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Algorithme} \renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{Liste des \ALG@name s} `\makeatother

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i have used \makeatletter\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Algorithme} \renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{Liste des \ALG@name s} \makeatother to change Algorithm--> Algoithme , Please i ask if you have an idea, i have one algorithme that i'd like to change Algorithme --> Pseudo Algorithme ? How can i do it please ? just one algo not all

Comment: I should think you can just \renewcommand the ....name command before the environment (and renewcommand it back again afterwards

Comment: Please can you explain more? i add \renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Pseudo Algorithme} \renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{Liste des \ALG@name s}   just before the algorithm?

Comment: oh sorry it has an @ in its name so you need to set it up slightly differently. I had assumed you still wanted it in the same list, making a separate list is a more extensive change (too much for a comment)

Comment: i post it as a question ?

Comment: yes I think so (I'm probably offline in a bit but someone could pick it up then)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85840/modify-algorithm-name-in-french

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The package defines all the fixed text words using simple macros that you can redefine with `\renewcommand` so for example

```
\newcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Require:}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Ensure:}}
\newcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\{#1\}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicend}{\textbf{end}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicif}{\textbf{if}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicthen}{\textbf{then}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicelse}{\textbf{else}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicelsif}{\algorithmicelse\ \algorithmicif}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendif}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}
\newcommand{\algorithmicfor}{\textbf{for}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for all}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicdo}{\textbf{do}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendfor}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor}
\newcommand{\algorithmicwhile}{\textbf{while}}
```

if you change `\newcommand` to `\renewcommand` and change the English words to French to redefine these commands after loading the package it should all work I think.

Comment: have you an idea please ?

Comment: Please edit the _question_ to have a complete document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Pour avoir “algorithme” au lieu de “algorithm” et “Liste des algorithmes” au lieu de “List of algorithms”, ajouter juste `french` comme option dans use packages comme suit:

<sup>In order to get “algorithme” in place of “algorithm” and “Liste des algorithmes” in place of “List of algorithms”, just add `french` as option for the package as follows:</sup>

```
\usepackage[lined,boxed,commentsnumbered, ruled,vlined,linesnumbered, french]{algorithm2e}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE! You will have more lack if you ask in English language :-)

Answer (score 6):

With

```
\usepackage{algorithm}  
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
```

My humble contribution to the French translation (thanks @David-Carlisle):

```
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{Liste des algorithmes}
\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithme}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicreturn}{\textbf{retourne}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicprocedure}{\textbf{procédure}}
\renewcommand{\Not}{\textbf{non}\ }
\renewcommand{\And}{\textbf{et}\ }
\renewcommand{\Or}{\textbf{ou}\ }
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Entrée:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Sortie:}}
%\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\{#1\}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicend}{\textbf{fin}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicif}{\textbf{si}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicthen}{\textbf{alors}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicelse}{\textbf{sinon}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicfor}{\textbf{pour}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{pour tout}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicdo}{\textbf{faire}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicwhile}{\textbf{tant que}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicelsif}{\algorithmicelse\ \algorithmicif}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendif}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendfor}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor}
```