# Modify Algorithm name in French

Tags: algorithms, languages, naming

This is my code:

```
\usepackage[section]{algorithm}  
\usepackage{algorithmic} 
\begin{document}
\makeatletter\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Algorithme}
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{Liste des \ALG@name s} \makeatother
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{My-algo}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Debut
    \LState instruction1
    \Fin
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

With this code I have Algorithme instead Algorithm. Please I ask if you have an idea, I have one algorithm that I'd like to change Algorithme --> Pseudo Algorithme ? How can I do it please? Just one algorithm, not all of them.

Comment: Would you please remove `\include{Chapter 1}` from your example (we obviously do not have this your file). Instead of that, put there the algorithm you want to modify, so that it is a Minimal Working Example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following minimal example defined `\newalgname{<alg name>}` that you can call from within an `algorithm` environment in order to change the name of the algorithm. Since you call it within `algorithm`, the redefinition of `\ALG@name` would be local, so it only affects the specific algorithm you're in.

> **Algorithme 0.1** My-algo
>   ...
>
> **Pseudo Algorithme 0.2** My-algo
>   ...
>
> **Algorithme 0.3** My-algo
>   ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[section]{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms  
\usepackage{algorithmic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newalgname}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\ALG@name}{#1}%
}
\newalgname{Algorithme}% All algorithms will be called "Algorithme"
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{Liste des \ALG@name s}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{My-algo}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE \textbf{Begin}
    \STATE instruction1
    \STATE \textbf{End}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
  \newalgname{Pseudo Algorithme}% This algorithm will be called "Pseudo Algorithme"
  \caption{My-algo}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE \textbf{Begin}
    \STATE instruction1
    \STATE \textbf{End}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{My-algo}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE \textbf{Begin}
    \STATE instruction1
    \STATE \textbf{End}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

---

It would also be possible, perhaps based on your requirements, to create an entirely new floating environment that is specific to "Pseudo Algorithme"s. This is possible using the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float), loaded by [`algorithm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) by default. It will have it's own counter and therefore will be numbered independently from the `algorithm` environment. Here's a quick view on that:

> **Algorithme 1** My-algo
>   ...
>
> **Pseudo Algorithme 1** My-algo
>   ...
>
> **Algorithme 2** My-algo
>   ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms  
\usepackage{algorithmic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\newfloat{pseudoalgorithm}{htb}{lop}
\floatname{pseudoalgorithm}{Pseudo Algorithme}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newalgname}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\ALG@name}{#1}%
}
\newalgname{Algorithme}
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{Liste des \ALG@name s}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{My-algo}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE \textbf{Begin}  
    \STATE instruction1
    \STATE \textbf{End}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{pseudoalgorithm}
  \caption{My-algo}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE \textbf{Begin}  
    \STATE instruction1
    \STATE \textbf{End}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{pseudoalgorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{My-algo}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE \textbf{Begin}  
    \STATE instruction1
    \STATE \textbf{End}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

---

Counter adjustments are also easy. The first example (in the `article` document class) used

```
\usepackage[section]{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
```

which passes the option `section` to `algorithm`. This implies that algorithm numbering will be by-section. That is, algorithms in section 7 (say) will be numbered 7.1, 7.2, and so on. If your document class supports `\chapter` (like `book` or `report`), then using

```
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
```

would do the same just for chapters. This also means that numbering of algorithms will be reset at the start of every chapter.

In the second example, no option was passed to the `algorithm` package, and numbering was continuous throughout the document (across any sectional unit).

To have the same numbering for your `pseudoalgorithm` environment, you can create it with

```
\newfloat{pseudoalgorithm}{htb}{lop}[<within>]
```

where `<within>` specifies the sectional unit that you want the numbering to be done with (`chapter`, `section`, ...). A discussion around the creation of a new float in this way is contained within the [`float` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/float/float.pdf) (section **2 The User Interface - New Floats**, p 2).

Comment: Thank you so much for answer :) i have Pseudo Algorithme 2 but it's the fisrt pseudo algo , please how can reinitialize it to 1?

Comment: @researcher: Do you want to include the pseudo codes in your List of Algorithmes? I assume you do *not* want to do that. Otherwise I would think it might be better to create a separate `pseudoalgorithm` environment. Let me know.

Comment: no it's Pseudo Algorithme,, but i should have Pseudo Algorithme 1

Comment: Unless you have plenty of both `Alg.` and `Pseudo Alg.`, I would suggest you to use one counter for both, i.e., have `Alg. 1, PsAlg. 2, Alg. 3, Alg. 4, ..., Alg. 57, PsAlg. 58, ...` I think that the reader might find it more convinient in the end.

Comment: i want Algoorithme 1, Pseudo Algorithme 1, is that possible ?

Comment: @researcher: Yes. I've added a newly created float environment `pseudoalgorithm` that has its own counter, and will create its own "List of..." file. Since you didn't mention whether that's important, I haven't added anything extra. However, it would be possible to create a command `\listofpseudoalgorithms` or include "Pseudo Algorithms" in the regular `\listofalgorithms`. It would be confusing though with your numbering request, so I left it out.

Comment: @Werner: please just one more question, how can i add the number of chapter with the number of algorithme, i want algo2.1 instead algo 1 ? is that possible ?

Comment: @researcher: I've added that discussion at the end of the answer.