# How to have two separate types of caption labels for algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I want to describe algorithms that have two parts: an interface specification and an algorithm.

The interface specifications should be labeled **Module** and the algorithm specifications should be labeled **Algorithm**. Moreover, I want the interfaces to be numbered separately from the algorithms.

The output should be something like the following:

```
Module 1: An interface specification
     Some interface spec...


Algorithm 1: An algorithm
     Some pseudocode...
```

The following, however, is what I'm currently getting:

[image: mwe output]

My code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Module: }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{An interface specification}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State Some interface spec...
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{An algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State Some pseudocode...
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are a couple of packages for typesetting algorithms, such as [`algorithm2e`](https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e), [`algorithmicx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx), [`algorithms`](https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms), or just a plain `tabbing` environment.  Please try out any of these first and then come back with a *specific* question.  I'm voting to close as unclear for now, but once you add a minimal example illustrating your *specific* problem we can reopen it.

Comment: On CTAN there is the dedicated category [`pseudocode`](https://ctan.org/topic/pseudocode) collecting all packages for typesetting algorithms.

Comment: You are maybe also interested in [UML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language).  There are also a couple of packages for that: https://ctan.org/topic/uml

Comment: I have added a MWE and rephrased my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is based  [on an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85845/4172) to the question [Modify Algorithm name in French](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85840/modify-algorithm-name-in-french):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\newfloat{module}{htb}{lop}
\floatname{module}{Module}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newalgname}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\ALG@name}{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{module}
\caption{An interface specification}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State Some interface spec...
\end{algorithmic}
\end{module}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{An algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State Some pseudocode...
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

It produces the following output:

[image: desired output]