# Two captions for algorithm in algorithm2e package

Tags: captions, algorithm2e

In my thesis, I need to describe both algorithms and cryptographic games. 
Currently I am using the algorithm2e and the algorithm environment for both.

Is there an option to 
specify dual captions so that games are captioned with Game and algorithms with Algorithm.

Note: In essence I am asking the question in [How to have two separate types of caption labels for algorithms?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328334/how-to-have-two-separate-types-of-caption-labels-for-algorithms) but with algorithm2e package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\captionof` together with a new float type within a normal algorithm environment.

This shows how to do it with either float or newfloat.  Interestingly, algorithm2e does not automatically load either.  I recommend newfloat as being more compatible with the caption package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=loga,listname=List of Games,placement=htp]{game}% log already used

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{Game}{htp}{logm}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\listofalgorithms

\listofgames

\listof{Game}{List of Games}

\begin{algorithm}[hp]
\caption{test 1}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[hp]
\captionof{game}{test 2}
\end{algorithm}


\begin{algorithm}[hp]
\captionof{Game}{test 3}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, you have been very helpful. Your suggestion is working. Any idea, on how to combine it with autoref in order to reference captionof{game} as Game.

Comment: IIRC, `\captionof{Game}{...}` calls `\refstepcounter{Game}` which should set up `\label` to save the counter name (Game).  If not, `\edef\@currentlabelname{Game}` (you will need to something about the @).