# How to write an algorithm in french? [Errors]

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, algorithmic

I am trying to write my algorithm in french language. I found [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74776/package-algorithmic-in-french) which works for me but with errors.

The errors are:

```
\algorithmicendelsif undefined
\algorithmicendif undefined
\algorithmicendfor undefined
```

I use the code provided by David Carlisle and I changed `\newcommand` to `\renewcommand` as he suggested. Everything is fine except with those errors. I mean the `for` changed to `pour`, `do` to `faire`, etc. But I still have errors and `fin for` instead of `fin pour`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I think this is the solution to my errors.

Change `\newcommand` to `renewcommand` except for those lines

```
\newcommand{\algorithmicelsif}{\algorithmicelse\ \algorithmicif}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendif}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendfor}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor}
```

So, I have to do this:

```
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Entrée:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Sortie:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\{#1\}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicend}{\textbf{fin}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicif}{\textbf{si}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicthen}{\textbf{alors}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicelse}{\textbf{sinon}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicfor}{\textbf{pour}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{pour tout}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicdo}{\textbf{faire}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicwhile}{\textbf{tant que}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicelsif}{\algorithmicelse\ \algorithmicif}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendif}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendfor}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor}
```